# PL/SQL Procedure to Delete Specific Rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-delete, data-integrity

Trying to create a stored procedure to delete all goods supplied by a distributor (x) as well as the references to the goods in my `LINE` table. My problem is there are 3 tables in total. So i need to delete the references from my `LINE` table first before deleting the items in `GOODS` table and I can't seem to figure it out correctly. I feel like I have it just need some help with a few syntax errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_DeleteProd(x IN INTEGER)
AS
    v_dcode    distributor.d_code%type;
    v_gcode    goods.g_code%type;
    v_gcode2   line.g_code%type;

 CURSOR v_delete_cursor IS
   SELECT goods.g_code, line.g_code , d_code
     FROM distributor
     JOIN goods ON (distributor.d_code = goods.g_code)
     JOIN line ON (goods.g_code = line.g_code);

BEGIN

  OPEN v_delete_cursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH v_delete_cursor INTO v_dcode, v_gcode, v_gcode2;
    EXIT WHEN v_cus_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    IF x = v_dcode THEN
      DELETE FROM line WHERE v_gcode2 = x;

      DELETE FROM goods WHERE v_gcode = x;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do a `FETCH` and `LOOP`? You can do this with DELETE statements much easier and cleaner.

Comment: No there isn't, just was introduced to pl/sql with using cursors and loops. Any simpler methods are appreciated, just trying to improve on my PL/SQL skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using correclty `AND` keyword

```
DELETE FROM line
WHERE v_gcode = x
AND
DELETE FROM goods
WHERE v_gcode = x;
```

should be

```
DELETE FROM line
WHERE v_gcode = x;

DELETE FROM goods
WHERE v_gcode = x;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, wasn't sure how to combine the statements correctly. Now I'm just getting an ambiguous column defined error somewhere where I first created my cursor?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify table name before d_code in your cursor select statement.